# Get middle number(s) of a list and put them in the start positions - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Ok, hi everyone. I've been trying this for a liitle while now with no success. What I want to do is get the middle number(s) of a list move them over to the starting position of the list. For example:

`[5,6,8,9,0]` => `[8,5,6,9,0]` //The `8` was moved over to the starting position.

`[5,6,7,8]` => `[6,7,5,8]` //The two middle numbers were moved to the starting position.

So far i've been able to get the two middle numbers of the list (code below) but that's where I get stuck and don't know how to move the numbers over.

My code:

```
middle :: [a] -> [a]
middle xs = take (signum ((l + 1) `mod` 2) + 1) $ drop ((l - 1) `div ` 2) xs
  where l = length xs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(:)` to prepend that item to the front of the list.  For the odd length case, you can do this as follows:

```
(xs !! middleLoc):(take middleLoc xs ++ drop (middleLoc + 1) xs)
where
    middleLoc = l `quot` 2
```

You will have to modify this for the even length case, which you might want to identify and deal with separately (ie- pull out and prepend two items).  I'll leave that for you to add.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it like this:

```
splitMiddle :: [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
```

Where it would return

```
(beginning, middle, end)
```

then you can just do

```
middleToFront :: [a] -> [a]
middleToFront xs
    let (beginning, middle, end) = splitMiddle xs
    in middle ++ beginning ++ end
```

To implement `splitMiddle`, I'd recommend breaking it up into a few steps

```
-- This is actually available in Data.List more efficiently,
-- but you can implement it yourself for practice
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt n xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)

splitMiddle :: [a] -> ([a], [a], [a])
splitMiddle xs =
    let l = length xs
        beginningLength = ???
        (beginning, rest) = splitAt beginningLength xs
        middleLength = ???
        (middle, end) = ???
    in (beginning, middle, end)
```

You'll need to fill in the `???`s, I'm not going to solve all of it for you ;)